# Set password for active directory lightweight directory services (ad lds) on .net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I am trying to create a new user and set their password in AD LDS using asp.net vb. I'm binding to an instance of a directory entry, which is working fine. And I can add a user without a problem. The problem is that I can't seem to set the password when I add the user. Is this the right way to set the password?

```
Dim objADAM As DirectoryEntry = BindToInstance()

Dim objUser As DirectoryEntry = objADAM.Children.Add("CN=Jimmy", "User")
objUser.Properties("sn").Value = "lloyd"
objUser.Properties("givenName").Value = "Jimmy Smith"
objUser.Properties("userpassword").Value = "THEPASSWORD"
objUser.CommitChanges()
```

This is the error that I get :

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072020) at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()

I've also tried this :

```
Dim objADAM As DirectoryEntry = BindToInstance()

Dim objUser As DirectoryEntry = objADAM.Children.Add("CN=Jimmy", "User")
objUser.Properties("sn").Value = "lloyd"
objUser.Properties("givenName").Value = "Jimmy Smith"
objUser.CommitChanges()
objUser.Invoke("SetPassword", New Object() {"123456789A$#"})
objUser.CommitChanges()
```

Which gave me this error :

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of  an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x8000500D): The  directory property
>   cannot be found in the cache. --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---  at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] args)

Comment: Does that password that you've set in the first attempt satisfy all password-related policies/rules?? Is it "complicated" enough?? Maybe that's the issue - you're using a password that doesn't pass the policies that are in place...

Comment: I just tried it with this `PA$sw0rd$#@!8t` and I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My coworker found a solution. You call CreateUserSetPassword to create the user and setup the password in one function call.

**FYI, if the set password fails, the user will already be set up, so you'll need to either delete the user or just call the SetPassword function again.**

**Class variables**

```
   Private Uri As String
    ' { get; set; }
    Private OuUri As String
    ' { get; set;}
    Private UserUri As String
    ' { get; set; }
    'You will want to set these two parameters somewhere in .config and pass to
    'or otherwise make available to this process
    Private userid As String = "danny123"
    Private pwd As String = "pa$$word1"
```

**New function**

```
Public Sub New(ByVal uri__1 As String, ByVal ou As String)
    Uri = uri__1
    OuUri = "LDAP://" & uri__1 & "/" & ou
    UserUri = "LDAP://" & uri__1 & "/CN={0}," & ou
End Sub
```

**CreateUserSetPassword**

```
''' <summary>
''' Creates new user and sets password
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userName"></param>
''' <param name="password"></param>
Public Function CreateUserSetPassword(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    Dim oGUID As String = String.Empty
    oGUID = CreateUserAccount(userName, password)
    If oGUID = String.Empty Then
        oGUID = SetPassword(userName, password)
        If oGUID = String.Empty Then
            oGUID = EnableUser(userName)
        End If
    End If
    Return oGUID
End Function
```

**CreateUserAccount**

```
''' <summary>
''' Create user in the AD-LDS
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userName"></param>
''' <param name="userPassword"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function CreateUserAccount(ByVal userName As String, ByVal userPassword As String) As String
    Dim oGUID As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Dim connectionPrefix As String = OuUri
        Using dirEntry As New DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix, userid, pwd)
            Dim newUser As DirectoryEntry = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" & userName, "user")
            newUser.Properties("userPrincipalName").Value = userName
            newUser.CommitChanges()
            newUser.Close()

        End Using
        'catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    Catch E As Exception
        oGUID = E.Message
    End Try
    Return oGUID
End Function
```

**SetPassword**

```
''' <summary>
''' Set password for the user in AD-LDS
''' </summary>
''' <param name="user"></param>
''' <param name="password"></param>
Public Function SetPassword(ByVal user As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    Dim oGUID As String = String.Empty
    Const adsOptionPasswordPortnumber As Long = 6
    Const adsOptionPasswordMethod As Long = 7
    Const adsPasswordEncodeClear As Integer = 1

    Const intPort As Integer = 50000
    Dim objUser As DirectoryEntry
    ' User object.
    ' Set authentication flags.
    Dim AuthTypes As AuthenticationTypes = AuthenticationTypes.Signing Or AuthenticationTypes.Sealing Or AuthenticationTypes.Secure

    ' Bind to user object using LDAP port.
    Try
        objUser = New DirectoryEntry(String.Format(UserUri, user), userid, pwd, AuthTypes)
        'Get object using GetDirectoryEntry
        'objUser = GetDirectoryEntry(user);
        objUser.RefreshCache()

        objUser.Invoke("SetOption", New Object() {adsOptionPasswordPortnumber, intPort})
        objUser.Invoke("SetOption", New Object() {adsOptionPasswordMethod, adsPasswordEncodeClear})
        objUser.Invoke("SetPassword", New Object() {password})
        objUser.CommitChanges()
    Catch e As Exception
        oGUID = e.Message & vbLf & vbCr & Convert.ToString(e.InnerException)
    End Try
    Return oGUID
End Function
```