# Forgot Active Directory Password Script in .NET

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm working on a web based "Forgot Password" to reset AD passwords, using LDAP. Well, I can unlock the user, but not change the password.

Here is my function :

```
Private Function ChangeLocalUserPassword(ByVal User As String, ByVal Pass As String) As Boolean
    Dim pinger As New Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    Dim usr As DirectoryEntry
    _de = GetDirectoryEntry()

    If _de Is Nothing Then
        'couldn't connect or find account
        MsgBox("_de is Nothing")
        Return False
    End If
    Try
        usr = _de.Children.Find("CN=" & User, "User")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("User could not be found!")
        Return False
    End Try
    Try
        usr.Invoke("SetPassword", Pass)
        usr.CommitChanges()
        usr.Properties("LockOutTime").Value = 0
        usr.CommitChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error is " & ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Here is my GetDirectoryEntry Function :

```
 Private Function GetDirectoryEntry() As DirectoryEntry
        Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry()
        dirEntry.Path = "LDAP://<SERVER>/ou=<OU>,dc=<DOMAIN>"
        dirEntry.Username = "<DOMAIN>\Administrator"          
        dirEntry.Password = "<PASSWORD>"
        Return dirEntry
    End Function
```

A side question - Anyone suggest to me, how I can get around hard coding the Admin user on the page? Would creating an IUSR with a few Admin privileges work?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an exception when you try to set the password?

Comment: Yes, if failing silently means it fails to do what you coded it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I went through this on a Lightweight Directory services implementation of AD.

[Set password for active directory lightweight directory services (ad lds) on .net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264464/set-password-for-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-ad-lds-on-net)

Basically you have to create the entry first then set the password.

Comment: I tried this. But wasn't able to change the password. Nor did I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

To reset password PwdLastSet is the key attribute.  If the value of PwdLastSet is set to zero then the user must change their password when they logon agin ([see article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

For your side question :

Create a new user in Active-Directory.

In the target Organizational Unit, or directly on the domain container, you just have to delegate the right of reseting the password to the new user. So your application manipulate just a user and password that is just allowed to reset password.

Comment: I only do this, if I want to force them to reset their password on the next logon, right?

Comment: Yes, for me that's what a forgoten password service have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group in AD, Create a User, delegate the password change option to the group, usually done at the OU level.  This is how most organizations do this when having a help desk functionality.
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Implementing-Active-Directory-Delegation-Administration.html